# Вырезать url картинки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте! Прошу помочь составить регулярное выражение для вырезки url картинки.
Вот часть текста:

```
{bl2TxDllZwX0","tbWidth":"92","tbHeight":"109","unescapedUrl":"http://cs9804.vk.me/u93342822/a_8f381de4.jpg","url":"http://cs9804.vk.me/u93342822/a_8f381de4.jpg","visibleUrl":"vk.com","title":"Ыфва \u003cb\u003eФыав\u003c/b\u003e | ВКонтакте","titleNoFormatting":"Ыфва Фыав |
```

С помощью сайта http://php-include.ru/regulyarnye-vyrazheniya-onlain
составил выражение

```
(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?(\w+.(jpg|png|gif))
```

но оно выбирает две url - ки подряд

Мне нужно от http: до .gif, .jpg

Comment: @PavelNET, может, стоит использовать более подходящий инструмент? Почему бы не распарсить строку как JSON и не вытащить нужное свойство?

Comment: Подскажите, как это сделать?   
На данный момент строку получаю таким образом:

    $str = file_get_contents($url);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($str, true);
$url = $data["url"];
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Сделал, как Вы написали, спасибо!